# which is the efficient way to iterate in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, tuples

I have to iterate one by one over 1 million records, which are stored in a list. And its value is present in a Pandas dataframe. I have to first find its value in the dataframe then perform some arthritic operation on it. And again store it in another Pandas dataframe. But it takes too much time to complete. So I have stored the value in a tuple and the performance has improved a bit but not as expected. Is there any way to optimize this? 
Below is sample code I have done.

```py
c2=['Fruits','animals',...]
list1=[]
for j in c2:
        data2=dataframe.loc[(dataframe['value'] == j)]
        data3=data2.describe()
        range1=data3.loc['max']-data3.loc['min']
```

Comment: looks like `groupby('value')`...

Comment: Considering the number of records. Have you looked in to concurrency and multithreading?

Comment: The problem isn't how you are iterating over `c2`, why did you think a tuple would work? It's that doing `data2=dataframe.loc[(dataframe['value'] == j)]` in a loop is incredibly inefficient. For starters, it iterates over the entire dataframe when you do `dataframe['value']`, which happens each iteration!

Comment: @phamot considering how inefficient the current implementation is, multithreading (which isn't effective in CPython for CPU bound tasks anyway) is not where the OP should start optimizing. It rarely is.

Comment: You should start with something like `dataframe.groupby('value').agg([np.min, np.max])` then you can subtract, then use `c2` as an index.

Comment: Thank you.@juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to use vectorized functions. Typing this in the blind:

```
c2 = ['Fruits', 'animals', ...]
tmp = dataframe[dataframe['value'].isin(c2)] \
        .groupby('value') \
        .agg(['min', 'max'])

df_range = tmp['max'] - tmp['min']
```